# python3 serial read v/s python 2

Tags: python, tcp, serial-port

I am using a raspberry pi to send data through TCP/IP where the raspberry pi is the server and my local windows machine is the client.

When I try to read data in python 3, I am getting weird characters for example:

```
send 20 decimal I receive @4

send 21 decimal I receive @5

send 22 decimal I receive @6
```

Below is the code running on my local machine:

```
import socket
host = '192.168.1.100'
port = 25000
mySocket = socket.socket()
mySocket.connect((host,port))
data = mySocket.recv(4).decode()
print (data)
```

Using python 2 is no problem and characters received with no decoding needed. I know I need to do some decoding on the data but not sure what. Any advise will be very helpful.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with sockets in Python, but a big difference between python 2 and 3 is the treatment of strings vs. bytes. They were synonymous in python 2 but are not in python 3 because of it's support for unicode.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this by using the following code:

```
data = mySocket2.recv(4)
newData = int.from_bytes(data, byteorder='big', signed=False)
```

The sender is sending uint32 data, that is obviously not-signed and is bigEndian. This has to be specified at the receiver side as well (my python3 script). If the sender changes and starts sending int8 data then I will need to update the receiver code to the following:

```
data = mySocket2.recv(1)
newData = int.from_bytes(data, byteorder='big', signed=True)
```

P.S. serial or TCP/IP receiving seem to follow the same logic in python, this means that data received requires the same encoding.